# node js delete go to wrong route

Tags: node.js, http, mongoose, ejs

I have app. I added DELETE feature by id. It looks like:

```
router.delete('/delete/:id', async function (req, res){
    console.log("I'm here..");
    try {
        var id = req.params.id;
        console.log("here!!!");
        console.log(id);
        var x = await Order.findByIdAndDelete(id).exec();
        await x.save();
        console.log("deleted!");
    }catch (exc){console.log("Error during deleting!")}
    res.redirect('back');

});
```

I have also form on my view (i use EJS).

```
<h1 class="mt-4">Dashboard</h1>
<p class="lead mb-3">Witaj <%= user.name %></p>
<% include ('./partials/messages.ejs')%>
<div class="row mt-5 float-left">
            Wszystkie zamówienia
            <table class="table float-left">
                <tbody>
                <% orders.forEach(function(value) { %>
                    <tr>

                            <form method="PATCH" action="/orders/order/<%=value.id%>">
                            <td>Id zamówienia <%= value.id %></td>
                            <td>Id klienta <%= value.userID %></td>
                            <td><input type="datetime-local" value= <%= value.dateStart  %>
                                min=<%= value.dateStart %> max=<%= value.dateFinish %>> data rozpoczęcia</td>

                            <td><input type="datetime-local" value= <%= value.dateFinish %>
                                min=<%= value.dateStart %> max=<%= value.dateFinish %> >data zakończenia</td>
                            <td>Cena: <%= value.total %></td>
                            <td>Ilość dni <%= value.numberOfDays %></td>
                            <td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Edytuj i akceptuj</button></td>
                            </form>
**THERE IS A BUTTON**       <form method="DELETE" action="/orders/delete/<%=value.id%>">
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="delete">Usuń</button></td></form>
                            <form method="POST" action="/orders/confirmOrder/<%=value.id%>">
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Akceptuj</button></td></form>

                    </tr>
                <% }) %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

Everything looks ok, and should work but it doesn't! Http request looks ok:

`GET /orders/delete/607d4b8b06e1aee2dfa901be? 404 84.803 ms - 2580` - but WebStorm shows `GET` in console. Quite strange. Why? It should shows `DELETE`. Id of order is okay - taken from database.

Console.logs from route like "here!!!", "I'm here.." aren't showed by console. So I think something is wrong with route.

Moreover after action my layout stopping work because "user is not defined" - yes, i check if user is logged in the layout. It indicates that something is wrong - I have the same situation with other action, but I fixed it. Here I spent 4hrs at night and haven't fixed it yet.
Please, show me what is wrong here.

Kind Regards!

Comment: does it delete the user  or not  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! HTML `<form>` doesn't support `DELETE`! I was forced to use jquery to send `delete` request, or to change `delete` to `post` in route and in the view.

Now my view and route look:

```
<td><button type="submit" id="del-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " value=<%=value.id%>>Usuń</button></td></form>
```

and route:

```
router.post('/delete/:id', async function (req, res){
 //body here
});
```

I left my answer. Maybe someone use it in the future.